# Initiate of the Faith - Healing Word in addition to Daily spell allowance

Tags: dnd-4e, multi-classing

Can you use the **Healing Word** power gained by the **Initiate of the Faith** feat as well as your normal Daily power allowance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

This is a multiclass feat power. You can use it in addition to all of your other class and racial powers that you are granted.

I think what you are referring to as "Daily power allowance" is the old restriction on magic item daily power usage. This has been errata'd and replaced with item rarity. There is no longer a restriction on the number of daily item powers that you can use.

Comment: I was referring to the number of daily powers your character can use, not from items. A level 1 wizard, for example, has 2 daily spells - one of which he prepares for the day. If he has a magic item with a daily recharge he can use that as well. I was wondering if this was a 3rd daily spell he can use.

Comment: Where is rarity introduced? I don't see it in the PHB errata.

Comment: IIRC Wizards are the only ones that get extra dailies that they have to choose between after an extended rest, and that only applies for those specific powers.  Once they are chosen though they act exactly as normal daily powers.  Powers granted from feats and such follow the same pattern as all other dailies where if you have them and they are unexpended you can use them.